# Postgres issue with storing time

Tags: postgresql, go

When I try to store time.Time{} in golang into a postgres db, the timestamp has a strange offset to it. Why can this be?
Also it seems like dates from around year 1900 are working, but earlier, it's a hit or miss.
Any help is much appreciated.

Here is a short code snippet to present the issue:

```
type TimeTest struct {
    Time time.Time
}
func (b *TimeTest) TableName() string {
    return "timetest"
}


func (repo RepoBe) TimeDemo() (timeBefore, timeAfter time.Time, err error) {
    t := &TimeTest{
        Time: time.Time{}, // Zero time.
    }
    repo.Logr.Debug("before DB", zap.Time("time", t.Time))
    if err := repo.DB.Create(&t).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    var u *TimeTest
    if err := repo.DB.First(&u).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    repo.Logr.Debug("after DB", zap.Time("time", u.Time))

    return &t.Time, &u.Time, nil
}
```

Output:

{"level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2023-11-09T10:39:23.273+0100","operation":"before DB","time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}

{"level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2023-11-09T10:39:23.303+0100","operation":"after DB","time":"0001-01-01T00:57:44.000+0057"}

Time zone in Postgres:
psql (12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show timezone;
TimeZone
Europe/Prague
(1 row)

postgres=#

Also, the table definition:

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;
CREATE TABLE public.timetest (
    "time" timestamp with time zone
);


ALTER TABLE public.timetest OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: See [Year 1 offset](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127965/why-does-time-zone-have-such-a-crazy-offset-from-utc-on-year-0001-in-postgres). Basically time zones did not exist then so the offset is based on solar time.